# Does the Azure Application Gateway support websockets

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I've setup an azure application gateway with two backend machines. The gateway has cookie affinity enabled and sockjs is used.

The browser initiates a websocket connection for which it receives an '101 Switching Protocols' response. However there is no communication over the websockets and sockjs falls back to long polling.

Does the azure application gateway support websockets? Is some configuration required to enable websockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amit Srivastava [MSFT]:

> Websocket support is being worked on and will be available shortly.

**Update**: I asked what shortly meant: the feature is planned for end May.

**Update 2**:
Amit Srivastava [amsriva@MSFT] on 12/08/2016

> Websocket is now supported on Application Gateway.

Comment: Hi Tom, can you share the example how you established the WebSocket connection?  I am unable to establish the connection.  Did you use the traditional server client and socket code or did you configure the gateway in some way to enable the support?  And one more thing, do the Gateway allows to connect to multiple microservices sockets at the same time?

Comment: What about in the V2 SKU?  When will websocket support be added there as well?

Comment: Got the signalR working over the Azure Application gateway..but somehow it fails for Azure Service Bus. Even when setting `TransportType` as `AmqpWebsockets` - can anyone share if it works for them ?